# How do i remove columns which contain 0 variance in Big dateset using Pandas?

Tags: pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

I would like to remove all 0 variable from columns.

I am trying to use:

```
X_train1 = X_train.dropna(how='any')
```

```
X_train1
```

---

Dataset Image:

[image: Dataset]

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you get the response, can you do two things please. 1. can you please post your code in clear text. It will help us look at the code. 2. Can you post desired result so we know what you are trying to get to.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to specify the column that from where you want to drop.

```
my_dataframe= my_dataframe[my_dataframe.employee_name != 0]
```

In the case that you want to drop in several columns, I would just write a list

```
   columns_to_drop = my_dateframe.columns # In case that you want to loop over all
   for col in columns_to_drop :
       my_dataframe= my_dataframe[my_dataframe[col] != 0]
```